# how to use the value after the callback

Tags: javascript, callback

In my application i'm isolating the networking in a method and performing a callback to get the JSON response , how can i use it afterward ?

```
getJson(url, acallback);

function getJson(url, callback) {
    Ti.API.info(" im here " + url);
    var jsonObject;
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.setTimeout(3000);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var jsonObject = eval('(' + this.responseText + ')');
        callback.call(jsonObject)
    }
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();
    Ti.API.info(" passed ");
};

function acallback() {
    return this;
}
```

Now my questions is , how can i use the returned output afterward ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should look like this:

```
function getJson(url, callback) {
    Ti.API.info(" im here " + url );
    var jsonObject, xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

    xhr.setTimeout(3000);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        callback(jsonObject)
    }
    xhr.open("GET" , url); 
    xhr.send(); 
    Ti.API.info(" passed " );
}

function acallback(json) {
      Ti.API.info("data from ajax: " + json);
}

getJson(url , acallback);
```

Notice that I removed the use of *eval* since it's bad practice to use that, as it says ([here](http://www.json.org/js.html)):

> The eval function is very fast. However, it can compile and execute
>   any JavaScript program, so there can be security issues. The use of
>   eval is indicated when the source is trusted and competent. It is much
>   safer to use a JSON parser. In web applications over XMLHttpRequest,
>   communication is permitted only to the same origin that provide that
>   page, so it is trusted. But it might not be competent. If the server
>   is not rigorous in its JSON encoding, or if it does not scrupulously
>   validate all of its inputs, then it could deliver invalid JSON text
>   that could be carrying dangerous script. The eval function would
>   execute the script, unleashing its malice.

Also, you better use the *var* keyword only once per scope.

---

## Edit

If you want to use the resulting json object from outside the scope of the callback, just define the callback in the scope where the json is needed, for example:

```
var obj = {
    x: 4,
    doit: function() {
        var _this = this;
        var callback = function(json) {
            alert(_this.x * json.y);
        };
        getJson(url , callback);
    }
}
```

The *json.y* part I just made up for the example of course.

---

## 2nd Edit

Alternatively, if you want to use the *call* option, you can do this:

```
function getJson(url, callback, bindto) {
    Ti.API.info(" im here " + url );
    var jsonObject, xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

    xhr.setTimeout(3000);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        callback.call(bindto, jsonObject)
    }
    xhr.open("GET" , url); 
    xhr.send(); 
    Ti.API.info(" passed " );
}

var obj = {
      x: 5
}

function myCallback(json) {
      alert(this.x * json.y);
}

getJson(url, myCallback, obj);
```

---

## 3rd Edit

If we're on the subject, I recommend using a nice trick, which is used in [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function%3abind), [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) and according to the MDN was [Introduced in JavaScript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
  var _function = this;

  return function() {
    return _function.apply(scope, arguments);
  }
}
```

You can read the [tutorial](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/) where I copied to code from.

Comment: i dont need to log the value , i need to use it actually and outside the scope of acallback()

Comment: I edited my original answer with how you can accomplish that.

Comment: *"you better use the var keyword only once per scope."* Why?

Comment: It's not a must, but you can read about it here for example: http://wonko.com/post/try-to-use-one-var-statement-per-scope-in-javascript. Also, I edited my answer again with another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The code that needs to use the output should be placed in `acallback` *(or placed in a function that's called from `acallback`)*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `callback.call(jsonObject)` should actually read `callback(jsonObject)`. Once you have invoked an asynchronous function, the way to get its value is via a callback. So, the function you pass in as `callback` will get the result. Say,

```
function myCallback(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: i dont need to log the value , i need to use it actually.

Comment: It's an example to explain the syntax. You can do anything you want with the `value` parameter which receives the `jsonObject`.

Comment: What if i want to use the value outside the scope of acallback() , thats actually my question

Comment: OP's original syntax using `.call()` is correct. @iyadalaqel: unless you make the call synchronous *(and you probably don't)*, you need to put your code inside the callback.

Comment: It is impossible. The callback receives the control flow, since once you start an asynchronous function it returns immediately in most cases, and the way it makes its result available is through a callback. By the moment your callback is invoked, the `getJson()` function has terminated, well, long ago...

Comment: @amnotiam: sorry, right, I just had hard time figuring why OP would want to have the result be `this`, especially if it is `null`, `undefined` or something.