# Retrieve variable from javascript object method callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

In my code I need to call an object method, retrieve the data from its callback, and pass it to another method or function.

```
someObject.getSomeData({option1:'value1', option2:'value2'},
    function(data) {
        doAwesomeStuff(data);
    }
);
```

However, the callback does not recognize any functions/objects/variables outside its scope.

What I've tried to do right now is wrap everything around a function.

```
var myData = '';
(function(myData) {
    someObject.getSomeData({option1:'value1', option2:'value2'},
        function(data) {
            myData = data;
        }
    );
});
doAwesomeStuff(myData);
```

However that doesn't work either.

Anybody know how to properly accomplish this?

Comment: What variables are you referring to by saying "outside its scope"?

Comment: > However, the callback does not recognize any
> functions/objects/variables outside its scope. That sounds a bit weird... where is doAwesomeStuff() defined?
If it's within the scope in which your call is placed (or into a broader one) it must be reachable.

Comment: it got defined and executed actually, but this was in nodejs and it was doing some data processing, and while I had a console.out statement to verify it got executed, it seems it got lost among other output. Seems like I hurried posting the question, I did that in school, I figured it out as soon as I got home and had a fresh look at it. thanks everyone for your help, I'll flag it for deletion or something :)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't really given us enough to go on there, but this statement:

> However, the callback does not recognize any functions/objects/variables outside its scope.

...is incorrect. A function has access to everything in scope where it's defined, so for instance:

```
var a = 10;
function foo(b) {
    bar(5);
    function bar(c) {
        alert(a + b + c);
    }
}
foo(12); // alerts "27"
```

Note how `bar` had access not only to `c`, but also to `b` (from the call to `foo`) and `a` (from the outermost scope shown).

So in your example, the anonymous function you're passing in as the callback has access to everything that's in scope where it's defined; `doAwesomeStuff` having been defined elsewhere presumably has access to different information, so you'll have to have the callback pass it any data it needs.

So I'm guessing your code looks something like this:

```
function doAwesomeStuff(data) {
    // ...
}

function doSomethingNifty() {
    var a = 10,
        b = 20;
    someObject.getSomeData({option1:'value1', option2:'value2'},
        function(data) {
            doAwesomeStuff(data);
        }
    );
}
```

...and you want `doAwesomeStuff` to have access to `a` and `b` from the call to `doSomethingNifty`. If so, your only options are to pass them into it as arguments (probably best) or export them to variables some scope that `doSomethingNifty` and `doAwesomeStuff` share (probably not ideal, too much like globals).

Comment: you're right, but it was something different, thanks for feedback! see my comment above on my own question for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) required variables to the function passed into the async method.

Also, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456068/how-to-use-the-value-after-the-callback/9456119#9456119) has a good treatment of the topic.

Your second version is not going to work at all, since you are trying to *immediately* access the data that are not yet available (not until the callback has been invoked.)

Comment: you're right about the callback, I was able to figure it out :) my function was poorly defined, see my comment on my question above

Answer (score 1):

Your first method:

```
someObject.getSomeData({option1:'value1', option2:'value2'},
    function(data) {
        doAwesomeStuff(data);
    }
);
```

looks fine.  Please provide more details on what is not working.

One problem could be that `getSomeData()` does not actually call the callback function.

`doAwesomeStuff()` can modify many different variables from the received data.  The variables which can be accessed by `doAwesomeStuff()` are those that were available to it (in its *scope*) where it was created..

Comment: you're right, but it was something different, thanks for feedback! see my comment above on my own question for more details